# How would i go inserting a table into a table?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

As the title states, I am trying to insert a table into a table. My goal is to have a table of every user, where I have their id be linked to a table with their warnings they got, but using .push() can only work with arrays, so is there a function to insert a table the way I want?

Comment: what database are you using? What have you tried so far? Your question is missing a few very important things. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question.

Comment: I am extremely new to nodejs, so I am not used to it, but the way I have things set up is a json file on my pc that is used as a datastore, as it makes it easy to change it manually if it errors, and the only thing i tried is .push, and I didnt want to make a for loop if i didnt have to.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a "table inside a table" to do this, simply have a primary key of the user id in the user table, and use it as a foreign key in the warnings table. **e.g.**

```
tableUser
| userID | username | 
---------------------
| 123456 | john doe |

tableWarnings
| userID | warnings |
---------------------
| 123456 | 2        |
```

hopefully that clears any confusion up, also I would strongly suggest against using json, its just a mess you won't want to deal with. Use [mongoDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) or [sqlite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3) - they are simply so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. I just upvoted the question and is perfectly valid.

What you ask CAN be done. Just not with SQL databases. For that, [Joe Moore's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67143532/1992152) answer gives you a good start.

Now my answer that might be a little bit more as a teaching new things you probably did not know so you know what you ask can be done, than a suggestion you go to that path. Though you are free to follow it.

For what you asked there are NoSQL databases. The one that can create a Table inside a table with the link you have is called [MultiValue databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiValue) that will give you exactly that. You can even set up cubes so easily. OpenMQ by Zumasys is one free option and Rocket Software D3 is another costly option that has an interface with Python but not with JS.

You will need to learn QMBasic, or QBasic, and Python if you want to follow this path.

Probably for you though, I highly suspect that you just need a many-to-many relationship like Joe Moore suggested.

Though, for a really high volume of data and data analysis, Multivalue is very very reliable if you pick the right database. Pun unintended and only understood by people that actually have worked with Multivalue.